# Stale State in Redux Store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a component named `<SearchForm />` which contains the following piece of code:

```
const insuranceDetails = useAppSelector((state) => state.search.insuranceDetails);
```

`useAppSelector` is a custom hook around `useSelector` that just provides proper type inferring for TS.

The `<SearchForm />` also has the following modal:

```
<InsuranceDetailsModal
  isOpen={isModalOpen}
  onClose={handleModalClose}
/>
```

The essential parts of the modal:

```
const handleConfirm = () => {
  dispatch(updateInsuranceDetails(insuranceDetails));
  onClose();
};
```

Basically this will dispatch an action to update the Redux store and then call `onClose` which is actually the `handleModalClose` prop we passed in:

```
const handleModalClose = () => {
  setIsModalOpen(false);
  search();
};
```

The key here is the `search` function, it's inside the `<SearchForm />` component, and here is the code for the `search` function:

```
const search = async () => {
  console.log(insuranceDetails);
};
```

`insuranceDetails` is the one I read earlier using the `useAppSelector` hook.

The problem is, I get the initial state of `insuranceDetails` where every property inside the object is empty.

For reference here's my slice:

```
const searchSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'search',
  initialState: {
    insuranceDetails: {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      insurance: { key: '', value: '', label: '', code: '' },
      birthDate: '',
      memberId: '',
    },
  },
  reducers: {
    updateInsuranceDetails(state, action) {
      state.insuranceDetails = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { updateInsuranceDetails } = searchSlice.actions;
export default searchSlice.reducer;
```

I am sure that Redux is updating the state, because it logs out the correct values when I am outside the search function, and when trying to call search from outside the modal, it actually works.

The `<SearchForm />` has the following function:

```
const handleSearchClick = async (e: React.MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  search();
};
```

when I call this from the `<SearchForm />` itself and not from the modal, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, your `handleModalClose()` references the old `search()`, which contains the old `insuranceDetails`.

I believe you need to find a way to tell the `SearchForm` to trigger the `search()` when the modal is just closed and when the value of insurance `insuranceDetails` is updated.

I believe a fix should be like:

`InsuranceDetailsModal`

```
const handleConfirm = () => {
  dispatch(updateInsuranceDetails(insuranceDetails));
  dispatch(updateShouldSearch(true));
  onClose();
};
```

`SearchForm`

```
const {insuranceDetails, shouldSearch} = useAppSelector((state) => state.search.insuranceDetails);

const search = async (detailsToSearch) => {
  console.log(detailsToSearch);
};

useEffect(() => {
  if (!shouldSearch) {
    return;
  }

  search(insuranceDetails);
  dispatch(updateShouldSearch(false));
}, [insuranceDetails, shouldSearch])
```

Please also implement the missing state value and reducer for `shouldSearch`.

Comment: Everything clicked when you said "handleModalClose() references the old search(), which contains the old insuranceDetails", instead of modifying my reducers and using the "shouldSearch" state variable, I ended up modifying the search function to take in an argument, and I would just pass the insuranceDetails directly to the "onClose" function, and that in turn calls search with the same parameter. Thanks a lot for the help!